# Get the x and y after touch drag fabric JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, touch-event

I have a little question about fabric JS :)

Here is the problem :

I have a function using the event : `canvas.on('mouse:up', function(evn)..`
In this function i detect when the selectedObject is over another object.

When it's done, i remove the selected object  like in this jsfiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/jgruwse0/

The problem is : that doesn't work with touch event, i would like to know the touch "end" positions; or even get something like `object:modified` (which does not seem to work with touch event) triggered after a drag and drop with touch

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/jgruwse0/33/).

Make use of [getPointer](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getPointer) method to get the pointer position.

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(evn) {
 var point = canvas.getPointer(evn.e);
}
```

Comment: OP asking about touch events

Comment: @MarsAndBack, internally fabricjs is handling touchend as mouseup.